# clearing app activity history when home button is clicked

Tags: java, android

I am creating a notification with pending intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Dialog.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intent, 0);
```

This will open a dialog activity.If i click close this dialog by clicking on home. next time i  click on app iconf from recent menu it again opens the dialog activity which i dont want .
I want my main app class to be opened always.

How do i do it?

Comment: kill your DialogActivity on its onPause()

Answer (score 0):

You can set the android:noHistory="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.launcher.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
/>
```